# Which elasticsearch analyzer should I use?

Tags: elasticsearch, tokenize, analyzer

I'm creating a search engine for videogames with about 100.000 entries and want to index them with Elasticsearch.

I played around with some analyzer configurations, but I'm not quite sure what configuration is the best for ecommence products.

My current setups looks like this:

```
:filter => {
  :en_stop_filter => {
      "type" => "stop",
      "stopwords" => ["_english_"]
  },
  :en_stem_filter => {
      "type" => "stemmer",
      "name" => "minimal_english"
  }
},
:analyzer => {
  :ja_analyzer => {
        "type" => "custom",
        "tokenizer" => "kuromoji",
        "filter" => ["icu_folding", "icu_normalizer"],
        "char_filter" => ["html_strip"],
        "mode" => "search"
  },
  :en_analyzer => {
              "type" => "custom",
              "tokenizer" => "icu_tokenizer",
              "filter" => ["icu_folding", "icu_normalizer", "en_stop_filter", "en_stem_filter"],
              "char_filter" => ["html_strip"]
  }
},
:tokenizer => {
  :kuromoji => {
      "type" => "kuromoji_tokenizer",

  }
}
```

`en_analyzer` for english titles and `ja_analyzer` for japanese titles.

Should I use ngrams, or try other types of analyzers? 
It's hard for me to compare the search results; maybe someone has some practice in ecommerce searching and can help me out.